# Move Worksheet to String Variable

Tags: vba, excel

I am having trouble making a string variable equal to the cell in a worksheet since I get a type mismatch. I would also like to make a single string variable (SheetString) equal to all worksheet content. A portion of my code is below:

```
    Range("A1").Select
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
    LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Range("A1:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    rng.EntireRow.Delete
    LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    'MsgBox (Continue)
    Set rng = Range("A1:A" & LastRow)

    'For x = 1 To LastRow
        'RowString = cell(x, 1).Value
        'if instr(,RowString,("Sheet1").
    SheetString = Range("a1:a" & LastRow).Value
    MsgBox (Continue)
    IE.Quit
```

Thanks

Comment: it needs to be an array for more than one, is it an array?

Comment: @Bob have you tried any of the answers you reveiced here ?

Comment: Yes. Problem solved

Comment: so mark as answer and upvote the answer people worked on to assist you

Comment: @Bob please mark as answe one of the answer you got here and helped you. this is the way SO works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't  assign a string like this, if you want to asign the whole Range in ***Column A***, you nned a loop, like this:

```
For i = 1 To LastRow
    SheetString = SheetString & ";" & Range("A" & i).Value
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

See this example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim SheetString As String
    LastRow = 12 '<~~ Example
    SheetString = range("a1:a" & LastRow).Value
End Sub
```

You can't do this. You can store the entire column in an array though. For that you have to declare `SheetString` as `Variant` as shown below else you will get the `Type Mismatch` error as you are currently getting

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim SheetString As Variant
    LastRow = 12 '<~~ Example
    SheetString = range("a1:a" & LastRow).Value
End Sub
```

This will create an array which you can loop to access

```
For i = LBound(SheetString) To UBound(SheetString)
    Debug.Print SheetString(i, 1)
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a try.